# Red color palette for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking for a palette in gnuplot for red color from very-light-red to deep-red. I found a script for black here http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.3/pm3dcolors.16.gnu

I tried by changing `set palette functions red, red, red` in the above script, but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "legend" do you really mean "palette"?  The legend is the list of plot titles and samples; entries there will normally appear in whatever color the corresponding plot used.  The palette is the color gradient used for pm3d plots.  To define a gradient from white to deep red:

```
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "dark-red")
test palette
```

If you want more precise control over how light/dark the two extremes are you can provide instead hexadecimal descriptions of the RGB components. E.g. the above command is equivalent to

```
set palette defined (0 "0xffffff", 1 "0x8b0000")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I mean palette. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't know `test palette`.